# Clarification regarding domain definition

Tags: logic, relations, predicate-logic

I have been reading the fourth chapter of Velleman's `How to prove` book and this is the definition for domain which I have encountered:

Suppose $R$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$. The the domain of $R$ is the set

$ Dom(R) = \{ a \in A | \exists b \in B ((a,b) \in R)\}$

Now what is $ \exists b \in B ((a,b) \in R)$ in the above logical expression ?

Is it equivalent to $ \exists b \in B \land (a,b) \in R$ ?

Comment: Read it as "there exists a $b$ in $B$ such that $(a,b)$ is in $R$".

Comment: @mrp Thanks, but what does it logically translate into ?

Comment: It doesn't logically translate to anything, it is what it is. If you want the intuition behind it, the domain is the set of first coordinates of $R$.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks, that's what I wanted to hear. Can you probably expand that as an answer ?

Comment: @GitGud On deeper thinking, can't that be translated into $ \exists b (b \in B \land (a,b) \in R) $ ?

Comment: @Sibi $\forall x\in A(P(x))$ is an abbreviation of $\forall x(x\in A\to P(x))$ and $\exists x\in A(P(x))$ is an abbreviation of $\exists x(x\in A\land P(x))$, so yeah.. by definition they mean the same. This is explained at the end of page 68 and at the top of page 69 of the second edition in the section **Example 2.2.2**.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a "formal" treatment, we have to start from the concept of *ordered couple* : $\langle x, y \rangle$.

The we have the definition of *relation* :

> $R$ is a *relation* **iff** $\, \forall z(z \in R \rightarrow \exists x \exists y (z= \langle x, y \rangle))$.

From it, we can define the *domain* $Dom(R)$ of a relation $R$ :

> $Dom(R) = \{ x \mid ∃y (\langle x, y \rangle \in R) \}$.

From this, it follows that :

> $a \in Dom(R)$ **iff** $\, ∃z∃b(z= \langle a,b \rangle \land z \in R)$.

---

In general, we have to note that the "set abstraction" symbol $\{ \, \, \mid \, \, \}$ has the property :

> $y \in \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$ **iff** $\varphi(y)$.

Thus, if $R$ is a *relation* from $A$ to $B$, i.e. $R \subseteq A \times B$, we have that  :

> $a \in Dom(R)$ **iff** $a \in A \land ∃b(b \in B \land \langle a,b \rangle \in R)$.

Comment: I think $\exists y \exists y$ should be $\exists x \exists y$ in the first statement.

Comment: Also, I think it should be $z \in R$ in the first statement. Thanks again for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

These are called "bounded quantifiers", since we wish to bound the context of the objects over which we quantify. In reality, these are shorthands:

$$(\exists x\in X)(\varphi(x))\iff\exists x(x\in X\land\varphi(x))\\
(\forall x\in X)(\varphi(x))\iff\forall x(x\in X\rightarrow x\in X)$$

Recall that $\exists x\varphi(x)$ is true if we can find $x$ for which $\varphi$ holds; so by bounding the quantifier, $(\exists x\in X)(\varphi(x))$ we require that the witness $x$ came from $X$. And similarly for $\forall x\varphi(x)$.

So here, $\exists b\in B((a,b)\in R)$ means that we are limiting our search for  a witness to the set $B$.

Answer (score 0):

$\exists\,B\in B (a,b)\in R$.  $\text{dom }R$ is the set of $a\in A$ such that for some $b\in B$, the ordered pair $(a,b)\in R$.